# Update em duas tabelas SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, sql-update, sql-server-2012

Como faço para realizar um update ao mesmo tempo em duas tabelas diferentes?

Tenho uma tabela chamada `Tarefa` e outra chamado `VinculoReferencia`, ambas tem o campo `Taridinclusao` onde é esse campo que precisa ser atualizado ao mesmo tempo, e o campo `TarID`, que é a referência das tabelas.

Na *query* abaixo é um update simples se fosse pra atualizar somente na tabela `vinculoreferencia`, mas quero também que quando atualizar esta, atualizar também na tabela tarefa no campo `taridinclusao`:

```
update vinculoreferencia set taridinclusao = 168228 where tarid = 168261.
```

Comment: Com Stored Procedure você consegue fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entre as suas tabelas, qual possui a chave primaria?

Caso seja `tarid`, crie a *foreign key* com `VinculoReferencia` como *cascade on update*, assim ao atualizar `tarid`, `Taridinclusao` também será atualizado.

```
ALTER TABLE VinculoReferencia
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Taridinclusao
    FOREIGN KEY (Taridinclusao)
    REFERENCES Tarefa(TarID)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Referências:

- [Restrições de integridade referencial em cascata](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Quando usar ON UPDATE CASCADE <sup>en</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481476/when-to-use-on-update-cascade)